# Android - in-app billing and existing customers

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm planning on discontinuing Pro version of my app (DroidIn) and offer in-app billing instead. How do I support existing Pro customers in such case? Is there a way to grant user paid license without charging them a second time? Currently I require user to have both regular and Pro version running on the same device where Pro is simply a validator (~75K)
Any creative suggestions are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to convert LVL to In-App. IMHO, just keep the Pro version without maintaining it. Release the In-App version as a separate product, with some incentive to the existing Pro users to convert to the In-App version.